# Data scraping with Python lxml returns adblocker value

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am currently HTML scraping to get some data from a webpage for a bot I am creating in Discord. I have previously used lxml successfully to scrape HTML from a different website, however, the website I am trying to scrape right now is detecting an adblocker and as a result whatever data I try to scrape, I receive the same value;

my code is as follows
`import sys
from lxml import html
import requests

def main(arg):
    page = requests.get("https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/pc/" + arg)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

```
killdeath = tree.xpath('//div[@class="stats">K/d]/text()')
print(killdeath)`
```

The value I am getting is
`'\nPlease consider adding Fortnite Tracker to your adblock whitelist! Our ads support the development and hardware costs of running this site. Really hate ads? Become a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the website it says:

> To make use of our APIs we require you to use an API Key. To use the API key you need to pass it along as a header with your requests.

Did you add the header to the request?
Also I would suggest making the request in [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or a similar app so you actually see the whole response.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to add a header to my get request and got the correct information, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that the initial page you get really only has the "Please consider..." text, and a bunch of JavaScript that actually loads the content that you see.  (Try printing out page.content to see what you're actually getting.)

Anyway, because the requests library is not a full-blown web browser, it does not execute the JavaScript, so you just see the ad-blocker message.